# Tapkey Web API - Problem when Registering OAuth clients [Tapkey]

Tags: tapkey

I am trying to register OAuth client, following the docs, but none of the links containing `/developers` in the path are working for me. I am either getting redirected to the https://my.tapkey.com/AdminUI/ and infinite load, until i refresh the page, or getting status code 502 Bad Gateway.

The ones I am having problems with are:
https://my.tapkey.com/AdminUI/developers/oauth-clients
https://my.tapkey.com/AdminUI/developers/identity-providers.

I tried on different OS's, using proxy, but nothing worked for me.

I am trying to register OAuth client, and explore more of the TapKey web api, but this one is a blocker for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You caught us here - we have changed the website a bit, and updated documentation is on its way but not yet published. We are working on it right now.

Developer section has moved to Tapkey Integrator Portal available on https://portal.tapkey.io .
Use the same login credentials you are using with Tapkey.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I was able to open above urls using portal.tapkey.io.

Comment: Great to hear! We updated the documentation on developers.tapkey.io right now.